# World runs out of souls

Tags: story-identification

Short fantasy written by a Brit in the 1960s or 1970s. Maybe by Brian Aldiss, but I am not sure.

A medical process makes the entire human race immortal. After a time a strange thing begins to happen - babies are born with no emotions or empathy; they have no souls.

**The reason:** there is only a limited number of human souls, which are reincarnated again and again and again. With all souls immortal, there are no new souls for newborns. **The solution:** humans must begin to die again.

Comment: It is the Brunner story - I now remember the part about the holy man deciding to die. Thank you very much for you answers!

Comment: If one of the answers below satisfies you, please 'accept' it by clicking the checkmark on the left - this will mark the question as solved and also give a little extra thank-you to the answerer :-)

Comment: This could explain why kids these days care so little... now if you'll excuse me I have a lawn to defend.

Comment: Is there any way to get this on e-book. These are my favorite kinds of stories, but I can't seem to find a way to get them, other then maybe periodicals at a public library. (and there is no e-book.se

Comment: This question with corsiKa's comment makes perfect sense :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is *[The Vitanuls](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53848)* by John Brunner.

> "The Vitanuls" (1967) proceeds on the premise that the current
> population explosion, plus the introduction of a longevity drug, has
> used up the entire pool of human souls and that babies are being born
> mindless. An Indian holy man, once a noted obstetrician, chooses death
> in order to free his soul for another.
>
> <sub><sup>[Voices for the Future: Essays on Major Science Fiction Writers, Volume 2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WL159WqK27cC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=The%20Vitanuls&source=bl&ots=fVnRDjkx3b&sig=74FYO9u5WhCfofeKl37fnOIcL60&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI8PG4vOTOAhXLIcAKHTmVCsEQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=The%20Vitanuls&f=false)</sup></sub>

You can read an excerpt [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TGokAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT66&lpg=PT66&dq=I+think+that+is+uncivil+of+you.+The+teaching+of+Hinduism&source=bl&ots=4DwIBocrL7&sig=agBxMcfZPIIGLduLbGieSs3csik&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU5-afweTOAhUEKsAKHW__DO8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=I%20think%20that%20is%20uncivil%20of%20you.%20The%20teaching%20of%20Hinduism&f=false)

Answer (score 24):

I'm pretty sure this is John Brunner's "The Vitanuls".

It has an semi-immortality pill (not perfect and just rolling out):

> "I think I follow you," the matron said at length.  "I take it the anti-death pill is a success?"  ... "You in the rich countries like America and Russia have been trying for years to find a broad-spectrum specific against aging, and I think--knowing your countries by hearsay--that there must have been a loud angry argument over who should benefit first."

It takes place in India, which gives them the setup to bring in reincarnation as a Chekov's Gun:

> The matron gave him a chill stare.  "I think that is uncivil of you.  The teaching of Hinduism is that the soul is born again, throughout an eternal cycle, until it achieves one-ness with the All."

I can't provide direct page quotes for the ending (I was quoting from Google Books and they omit the next few pages), but [a summary](https://richardmurphy5.wordpress.com/2015/11/10/running-short-of-love/) does indeed indicate that babies do start getting born with a curious lifelessness, and it is the lack of enough human souls that is the cause.

And there is this line:

> "No, that's absurd.  You can't mean to maintain that we've run short of human souls, as though they were stored in a cosmic warehouse and issued off the shelf every time a child is born!"

Answer (score 2):

Is it [Brian Aldiss's *Hothouse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hothouse_(novel))?

I haven't read the entire plot summary, but here's [an excerpt from the book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bYHaPjthMFAC&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=brian+aldiss+babies+no+souls&source=bl&ots=8bI4D1m7eZ&sig=lN9DYnf1BL2eZUR269qYLyqr2CI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOxLv-u-TOAhWBLMAKHY7-DtUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=brian%20aldiss%20babies%20no%20souls&f=false) (emphasis mine):

> 'You are still young,' said the Chief Captive. 'You have entered a fresh life. Where are your souls?'
>
> Lily-yo and Flor looked at each other. In their flight from the wiltmilt **they had heedlessly thrown down their souls**. Haris had trampled on his. It was unthinkable!
>
> 'You see. You needed your souls no more. You are still young, and may be able to have babies. Some of those babies may be born with wings.'
>
> The Captive with the boneless arms added, '**Some may be born wrong, as we are.** Some may be born right.'

Comment: Hothouse plot isn't even remotely close to what OP has described